# WordPress custom taxonomies new/edit post autocomplete

Tags: custom-taxonomy, search, autocomplete

I hope I can find some help or advice here regarding custom taxonomies auto-complete (maybe there is a ready-plugin but I am not aware of it).

I have custom taxonomy which have around 500 items. So when I admin user create new post and need to choose one or multiple item in add/edit post screen, he needs to scroll down and search through all of those items. It is a lot of time-consuming job.

Is there any kind of auto-complete possibility that can be done for custom taxonomy, similar to tag auto-complete option?

Thank you

Comment: you can use jquery autocomplete for that

Comment: i implemented that for a different proj recently, not with taxonomies though

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit your solution, of course not to do it for me, but some guidance, please :)

Comment: i can do it too (if paid ;)) - explanation is : use jquery autocomplete library and use it to receive the list while writing as autocomplete :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember WP core doesn't do this natively, though I think there are/were some considerations about adding select2 for tasks like this. Might be mistaken on this.

However there are *a lot* of frameworks around, which implement additional UI for things like this. It's pretty common feature in them. I tend to use Meta Box, which should be able to do it, but so can others.

Answer (score 0):

There are many jQuery plugins designed specifically for this functionality. Check these ones out: http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-multiselect-plugin/